# How to split text data for LSTM training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm using Colab Pro TPU that offers up to 35 GB of memory. My dataset contains 650,000 sequences. I'm trying to use BiDirectional LSTM to predict the next word.

When I attempt to generate the binary_class vector using to_categorical(), it crashes because of memory limits. I took the first 200k sequences, trained the model, accuracy almost stops at around 65%. Before tweaking the hyperparameters, I wanted to feed the whole dataset and train the model. Is it possible to split the dataset, generate sequences, join them for training?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a `TimeDistributed` layer anywhere?

Comment: 650 000 sentences should probably take 100 - 200 MB which is nothing. Are you sure it is a reason of crash ? I would try to reduce batch size first

Comment: I'll try batch size but this is crashing way before training. Its crashing at to_categorical(sequence_arr,vocab_size) .. vocab_size ~10k

Comment: @SusmitAgarwal, no.any example?